# how to set file pointer with fseek

Tags: c, file, fseek

I know my file pointer is at end of the line after printing this string: "xyz".

How can I get it to the start of the line? (pointing to x)

```
offset = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, offset - sizeof("xyz") , SEEK_SET);
```

Above doesn't seem to work.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the offset by issuing a `beginning = ftell(fp)` before reading/writing you "xyz". 
Then `fseek(fp, beginning, SEEK_SET);`

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof("xyz")` will return 4 since you have the three characters plus the terminating null. You should use `strlen("xyz")` instead or subtract one from the sizeof result to account for the null.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>As the type of `"xyz"` is `char const *`, `sizeof("xyz")` will return the size of a standard pointer, typically 4 or 8.</strike>

Also note that `fseek` does not work in **text** mode, only if the file has been opened in binary mode, as it's not possible to tell how big newlines are on the underlying host system.

In addition, it's better to use `SEEK_CUR`, as it will more the read/write point relative to the current position.

Comment: No, the type is const char[].  David Paxson got the value resulting from `sizeof()` correct.

Comment: Of course. Now that you mentioned it, I remember actually using it (when trying to write the worlds smallest *Hello World* program in C on the Amiga, some 15, 20 years ago).